# Probability and Statistics Question

Tags: probability

At an ice cream counter, a special is offered on two scoops, served in a bowl, with two toppings sprinkled over both. There are 24 flavors of ice cream available, and 8 toppings. In how many different ways can the special be ordered if the scoops can be the same or different, but the two toppings are different?

What I have tried:

(24^2)(8^2) = 36864

I wanted to confirm if this is the correct way to calculate the answer.

Comment: You are badly overcounting.  You have to take into account that choosing (vanilla, chocolate) is the same as choosing (chocolate, vanilla).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close but missing the important fact that the two toppings are different.

You hav identified that you have $24^2$ possible ways of picking the scoops. But for the toppings, you have $8$ choices for your first topping but only $7$ for your second because you have already used one as the first topping and the second one must be different from the first.

Thus a better answer is:

$$
24^2 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 =  32,256
$$

Besides this, you are also double counting similar flavors and similar toppings. This is a combinations question not a permutations question. For ex. ordering a Chocolate and a Strawberry scoop is the same as ordering a Strawberry and a Chocolate scoop. Similarly, putting sprinkles and coconut on both scoops is the same as putting coconut and sprinkles.

**Ways of picking scoops**

There are $24\cdot 23$ ways of picking any two different flavors and for each combination of two flavors, there will be one duplicate. That is, for ever order of flavors $\left<A,B\right>$, you have the duplicate $\left<B,A\right>$. Thus we can divide our answer by $2$ to get rid of these duplicates, giving: $\frac{24\cdot23}{2}$ ways of picking two different flavors. In addition to this you could pick, in $24$ different ways, two of the same flavors giving a grand total of:

$$
\text{Ways of picking scoops} = \frac{24\cdot23}{2} + 24 = 300
$$

**Ways of picking toppings**

We are picking different toppings and again, for each choice $\left<A,B\right>$, we will have the duplicate $\left<B,A\right>$ so we must divide by $2$ again to get rid of these duplicates. This gives:

$$
\text{Ways of picking toppings} = \frac{8\cdot 7}{2} = 28
$$

Thus multiplying these gives the total ways:
$$
\text{Total Number of Different Orders} = 300\cdot28 = 8400
$$

Comment: @gowrath Thank you! Your explanation was excellent.